# This browser does not support WebSockets

Tags: c#, winforms

im beginner in c# windows form
in windows form , i use webBrowser control and in form load i write this code

```
private void Lobby_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     webBrowser1.Navigate(string.Format("http://1.1.1.1:1111/?firstData={0}&SessionKey={1}", "test", "E47ED45FA0546BABEF2B"));
}
```

but i get this error

> Error: this browser does not support WebSockets

How I can fix it?

Comment: What page are you actually using within the WebBrowser control?  Sounds like it's that page that's showing that error.  I'm guessing that whatever version of IE that's hosted inside WebBrowser (it always seems a bit tricky to nail down exactly what version is used, or emulated) doesn't support Web Sockets...

Comment: @JamesThorpe thank you for answer, my ie version is 11,

Comment: Your _IE_ version is 11, but the thing that's run inside the WebBrowser control is usually some cut down version of the rendering engine - it doesn't usually correlate directly with the installed IE version.

Comment: @JamesThorpe What should I do?